# Merge tables where NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, merge

I have two tables like this

Table 1

```
+-----------+----------+-------+-------------------+
| AGENCY_ID | LOCAL_ID | CLASS |      LRS_ID       |
+-----------+----------+-------+-------------------+
|       651 | 1        | NULL  | 10200000690000001 |
|       651 | 2        | NULL  | 10200000690205B01 |
|       651 | 3        | NULL  | 10200000690293C01 |
|       651 | 4        | NULL  | 10200000690293D01 |
+-----------+----------+-------+-------------------+
```

Table 2

```
+-----------+----------+-------+-------------------+
| AGENCY_ID | LOCAL_ID | CLASS |      LRS_ID       |
+-----------+----------+-------+-------------------+
|       651 | NULL     | 1     | 10200000690000001 |
|       651 | NULL     | NULL  | 10200000690000091 |
|       651 | NULL     | 7     | 10200000690205B01 |
|       651 | NULL     | 1     | 10200000690293C01 |
+-----------+----------+-------+-------------------+
```

And I want the result to be

```
+-----------+----------+-------+-------------------+
| AGENCY_ID | LOCAL_ID | CLASS |      LRS_ID       |
+-----------+----------+-------+-------------------+
|       651 | 1        | 1     | 10200000690000001 |
|       651 | 2        | 7     | 10200000690205B01 |
|       651 | 3        | 1     | 10200000690293C01 |
|       651 | 4        | NULL  | 10200000690293D01 |
+-----------+----------+-------+-------------------+
```

Taking table 2 and merging the non-NULL values to table 1. Here I only specify the `CLASS` field but there are 50+ fields that are always NULL in Table 1 and may or may not be NULL in table 2. So just specifying manually which fields I want is the problem, I want it to automatically replace it if its NULL and table 2 has it.

Key things to note is that LRS_ID is the JOIN key. LRS_ID that exist in table 2 and not table 1 don't exist in the output. LRS_ID that exists in table 1 but not table 2 remain but CLASS remains NULL.

Comment: If conflicting non-NULL data exists in both Table 1 and Table 2, which takes precedence?

Comment: There shouldn't be. But Table 1 should takes preference if thats the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `left join` to get your expected output like this:

```
select
    t1.AGENCY_ID,
    ISNULL(t1.LOCAL_ID,t2.LOCAL_ID)LOCAL_ID,
    ISNULL(t1.CLASS,t2.CLASS)CLASS,
    t1.LRS_ID
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on
    t1.LRS_ID = t2.LRS_ID
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99591/5/0)

Comment: CC - Correct and Concise.

Answer (score 1):

Just join the tables and find the first value you want. 
Select:

```
select
    t1.AGENCY_ID,
    ISNULL(t1.LOCAL_ID,t2.LOCAL_ID)LOCAL_ID,
    ISNULL(t1.CLASS,t2.CLASS)CLASS,
    t1.LRS_ID
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on
    t1.LRS_ID = t2.LRS_ID
```

Reverse ISNULL to give priority to t2.

To update:

```
update t
    LOCAL_ID = ISNULL(t.LOCAL_ID,t2.LOCAL_ID),
    CLASS = ISNULL(t.CLASS,t2.CLASS)
from table1 t
inner join table2 t2 on
    t1.LRS_ID = t2.LRS_ID
```

Comment: Your approach misses records where the `LRS_ID` value only exists in `table2`.  It also misses records where the `LRS_ID` value only exists in `table1` because you chose an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: If there is no LRS_ID on table1 what is the identifier it should be considered?

Comment: This indeed misses the issue where `LRS_ID` exists in `table1` and not in `table2`

Comment: @LDMJoe - OP writes: *LRS_ID that exist in table 2 and not table 1 don't exist in the output.*

Comment: @SQLPolice I took that to be cited as part of the problem.

Comment: @LDMJoe That's right, that could have that meaning. Inverse, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

First you get a distinct list of all the LRS_ID's from both tables, as some may exist in one table but not the other.  Then, outer join to both tables based on the LRS_ID.  Finally, use COALESCE to get the first non-null value from either table for each field.

```
SELECT
    DerivedAllLRS_IDs.LRS_ID,
    COALESCE([Table 1].AGENCY_ID, [Table 2].AGENCY_ID) AS AGENCY_ID,
    COALESCE([Table 1].LOCAL_ID, [Table 2].LOCAL_ID) AS LOCAL_ID,
    COALESCE([Table 1].CLASS, [Table 2].CLASS) AS CLASS
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        LRS_ID
    FROM
        (
        (SELECT LRS_ID FROM [Table 1])
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT LRS_ID FROM [Table 2])
        )DerivedUnion
    ) DerivedAllLRS_IDs
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table 1] ON DerivedAllLRS_IDs.LRS_ID = [Table 1].LRS_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Table 2] ON DerivedAllLRS_IDs.LRS_ID = [Table 2].LRS_ID
```

Note that if you are looking to modify the underlying data, it will require two passes.  First, an `UPDATE` statement on existing records in `[Table 1]` to plug the missing info that exists in `[Table 2]`, then a set of `INSERT` statements to get data for rows where the `LRS_ID` only exists in `[Table 2]` into `[Table 1]`.

Comment: This works for where `LRS_ID` exists in `table1` and not in `table2`. However, it includes records where `LRS_ID` exists in `table2` and not in `table1`, I want to ignore these.

Comment: I thought you were saying that behavior was part of the problem you were encountering, not a requirement.  My bad on the interpretation of the OP, sorry.